# Angular JS double requests

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

Here's example setup:

```
var editor = angular.module("editor",['ngResource']);
editor.factory("Provider",function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/test/1').get();
})

function ctrl($scope,Provider){
    $scope.sections = Provider; 
}
```

My problem is that in firebug i see that there are two GET requests being sent: one at /api/test/1 and one at /api/test/1/.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you creating multiple instances of the ctrl?  Also you have  a syntax error missing a " in your code.  If you have multiple controllers of this type being used then for each one the function will be called which in this case is calling get() on the $resource.  If you want a single instance use service instead of factory.

Comment: No I'm using "ctrl" only once, just tried with service but it was the same.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle out of this or a plunkr to show the issue in action?  I've only been using $http within my services thus far but haven't seen any double call behavior... though I've mostly been testing in Chrome.

Comment: Actually $http did the trick, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that just adding `/#` after `/1` solved the problem.

Change:

```
return $resource('/api/test/1')....
```

to:

```
return $resource('/api/test/1/#')....
```

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completion, I believe `$http` will 'short circuit' within your folder structure, simply grabbing the resource where you point it to do so and is accessible within the project, whereas `$resource` is geared towards communicating with an external source, often an external RESTful api. In applications where I implement this, I often define a variable where my various `$resource` definitions can access it, as you'll see in my defined variable `API`

It also appears in this case that you are passing `1` as some sort of id.

```
var API = 'http://localhost\\:#####/api/';

editor.factory('Provider', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(API + 'test/:id', { id: '@id' }, { });
});
```

Then to implement

```
function ctrl($scope, Provider){
    var myVarToPass = 1;

    Provider.get({ id: myVarToPass }, function (result) {
        //single call here as soon as controller loads
    });
}
```